# How do I access the nth character(s) in an NSString?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

I've got HEX colors as NSStrings and want to check if a particular string contains an F at the first, third, or fifth character, but to ignore it if it contains an F at the second, fourth or sixth character.

This is to identify if the color in question is a light color or not.

I searched for this, but only found answers regarding how to find character ranges.

Comment: Convert the NSString to a C string and then index into it?

Comment: You could always apply what you found: get a range containing a single character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use `characterAtIndex`?  You can use the method to retrieve the string at the first, third and fifth character (of course one at a time) and compare it with F.

Note that all your HEX colors must be 6 characters. Sometimes, you can represent a color with only three hex values (eg. FFF would still give you white in HTML). So if your color is represented using three chars only, and you try to get the char at index 5, the method will throw an 'out of range' exception.

Comment: I'm glad *we* could help. :-)

Comment: Can't upvote yet, so stuck with all three answers so far equally helpful and only able to give one "best answer". :/ Thanks to all!

Comment: OT from the original question, but just noticed that probably hex lightness could be better determined by any odd indexed char in any length string being a letter. I think. N00b trial and error methods going on here.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the characterAtIndex member of NSString.

```
char fifthChar = [yourString characterAtIndex:5];
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Daniel Pereira says, you can use the `-[NSString characterAtIndex:]` method to check characters.

```
NSString *string = /* Assume this exists */;
if ([string characterAtIndex: 1] == 'F' || \
    [string characterAtIndex: 3] == 'F' || \
    [string characterAtIndex: 5] == 'F')
{
    // F at odd-indexed character
}
else
{
    // Do other stuff here...
}
```